# How to namespace aws-sdk-php-laravel in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, aws-sdk

I've just started using laravel 5 and not quite familiar with namespacing. So as the title says, how do I namespace aws-sdk-php-laravel package in my controller?

I'm trying to use the amazon sns to push notification message to my iOS app.

I've tried

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

and got the error:

> Fatal error: Class undefined: App\Http\Controllers\AWS

Comment: @michael, No I don't have. I intend to use the package here. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel I was thinking I was using the wrong path in my namespacing.

Comment: Paste the line that's resulting in the exception. the "use" statement you pasted is not related to the error

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo the line was $sns = AWS::get('sns'); I added a backslash and its working now. Thank you

Comment: Good to know. That's what I thought. Without use statement or fully qualified classname, PHP tries to load the class from current namespace.

Comment: The facade is `AWS` and registered globally, so `use AWS;` should work. Alternatively you can add a back slash when you use the class `$sns = \AWS::get('sns');` .

Comment: Have you included the file to your composer.json?  If so, use the storage facade after configuring filesystems.php

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to access a Facade here inside one of your controllers.

Try adding a `use` statement at the top:

```
use Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade as AWS;
```

Or preceed `AWS` in your current code with a backslash (`\AWS`) to tell PHP it should be looking for a `AWS` class in your current namespace (`App\Http\Controllers`) but in the root namespace `\`.

Answer (score 0):

config/app.php add

```
        'AWS' => Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::class,
```

then add a use statement at the top, where u want to use:

```
use AWS
```

or you can use @hannesvdvreken style